# Как проверить элемент внутри RecyclerView который если таких RecyclerView больше 1-ого с одинаковым id на одном экране

Tags: java, android, kotlin, test-automation

Нужно написать UI тест с использованием Espresso или UI Automator.

Есть экран. В нем добавляются фрагменты с RecyclerView. В каждом фрагменте один и тот же список, но разные айтемы. Нужно проверить, что в определенном RecyclerView находится нужный мне элемент и желательно проверить, что он на корректной позиции.